# Django first app from . import views issue

Tags: python, django

***SOLVED: I was using Sublime Text 3 as an IDE and it didn't like the dot in 'from . import views'. I switched to Visual Studio Code and everything is working fine. Thanks to everyone that responded with suggestions and helped!

I'm learning Django by using the Writing your first Django app documentation from the site. I have edited three files.

In the file urls.py in the polls folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

In the urls.py in the mysite folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

In the views.py in the polls folder:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello once again.')
```

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 2.1.2, could an updated version of either affect this?

Here is error I get from trying to run the server:

`File "D:\DjangoPractice\mysite\polls.urls.py", line5, in <module> 
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'index'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error says your views file does not have an "index" function. Did you define one? (And don't post links to pictures of code, put the code here in the question.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman The definition is definied in views.py like it says to in the documentation. It just returns simple Http

Comment: *Show that code*. Python is telling you it is not found.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry this is my first time with stackoverflow I'm not sure how to show my code in comments

Comment: You shouldn't show your code in comments. You should show the code *by editing the question*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. I added it all now.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are adding this line `path('', views.index, name='index')`, in your project `urls.py`, but not on the app `urls.py`.

When you do `from . import views`, you are looking for a views file in your project folder, but the views file is inside polls folder.

You can fix this by doing this in your urls.py `from polls import views`

Comment: When I try from . import views.ViewName it tells my SyntaxError: invalid syntax and points to views.ViewName

Comment: from django.http import HttpResponse
    
    def index(request):
     return HttpResponse('Hello once again.')

Answer (score 0):

Change it as `from .views import *`
or `from .views import ViewName`

Comment: Thanks for responding! I changed it to from .views import ViewName
Then changed the actual code to

urlpatterns = [
 path('', ViewName.index, name='index'),
]

but got the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ViewName' from 'polls.views'

Comment: what is index means?

Comment: Could you share me the tutorial you are following ?

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: before adding the polls page I was able to run the server so it was working up until this point.

Comment: In your urlpattern index is view name. So the correct usage is  path('', index, name='index').

Answer (score 0):

```
from polls import views
```

add your app in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it was an editor issue like you mentioned. It's not a sublime or a VS Code problem. The problem came up because of the way you called the index function.

I just feel it's better to make sure we got it all right for posterity's sake. Many will come this way for solutions in future.

Comment: Changing " from . import views " to " from .views import * " or "from .views import index "  and changing " path('', views.index, name='index'), " to "path('', index, name='index')," solved the problem.